# Webserver on Solaris 10 + zones. How to do it properly?

Tags: solaris, nginx, opensolaris, solaris-zones, openindiana

I have 1 real IP and many websites. Initial idea was to separate each website into it's own exclusive-ip (vnic) non-global zone. MySQL server have it's own non-global zone.
Question is: what is the best way to setup nginx reverse proxy to handle all incoming traffic, pass is over to proper zoned backend and serve static content for every website?
Few really tricky solutions comes into my mind:
1) install nginx in global zone and have nginx visibility to every zones. AFAIK it is bad idea to have inet daemons running in global zone
2) install nginx in non-global shared ip zone and lofs mount document roots from each non-global zone into nginx zone. No sure how good this solution as well
3) install nginx in every non-global zone to serve static/pass to backend and have separate non-global shared ip zone with nginx to handle all incoming traffic and then pass to appropriate nginx in another zone? Too complicated

Any ideas on what is the Solaris way to do that?

Comment: First of all in my book it is best practice not to stick anything into global zone. Once you've gone down the zone route you realize that nothing belongs there. Global zone is for management purpose. Just my personal opinion. (in more recent versions versions of Solaris, v11, I cannot think of anything that *requires* to live in global zone. Btw is Solaris 10 really a requirement for you?? .. or is it ok to use Solaris 11 ??).

Comment: I'm using openindiana. Not Solaris 10 strictly, but close to. Solaris 11 isn't free

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "free". FYI: You can download and use Oracle Solaris at no cost when used for "developing, testing, prototyping and demonstrating your applications" and in addition there's some further provision for educational institutions. [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/solaris-cluster-express-license-167852.html). I can see why your use-case may fall outside of this.